# How do I know which permissions I need to set up for an Microsoft Identity Platform/Azure AD/MSAL app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I know how to register an all in Azure AD. I also know how to retrieve an access token with MSAL. When I make a request I get this error:

```
$ curl https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInsufficientPermissionsInAccessToken",
    "message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Fast.Profile.Core.Exception.ProfileAccessDeniedException' was thrown.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-06-11T18:41:12",
      "request-id": "c5af5903-d4d1-4a6c-bdf4-9c059f865345",
      "client-request-id": "c5af5903-d4d1-4a6c-bdf4-9c059f865345"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to know which API permissions and scopes you need to set up from the error message?

Answer (score 0):

***Setting up API permissions and scopes depends on the request you are making to call Microsoft Graph.***

You can find the required permissions for every Graph API request via [**Microsoft Graph REST API v1.0 reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

> Please note that **[`/me`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-signed-in-user-request)** is used to get user information of signed-in user.

Check the below **note** while calling `/me` endpoint :

[image]

Required **[permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)** for calling `/me` endpoint are:

[image]

***I tested in my environment and got the profile successfully with Delegated permission like below:***

[image]

***API Permissions*** that I have given to the app:

[image]

You can find similar kind of problem raised in **Microsoft Q&A** below:

[**ErrorInsufficientPermissionsInAccessToken - Microsoft Q&A**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/276867/problem-to-list-profilecardproperties.html)

Comment: If I understood it correctly you can't know the permissions required with just the error message. You'd have to either check that all permissions of all requests are OK manually or just ask in a forum like Microsoft Q&A.

Comment: The error message `ProfileAccessDeniedException` says you don't have permissions to access the profile. To resolve that, you have to manually check whether the required permissions are granted or not. If error still occurs even after granting the permissions, then you can raise **Azure Support request** or ask in a forum.